How to extract document page associated to each chunk extracted from PDF in custom WebApiSkill
I have the following custom WebApiSkill:
@app.route(route="CustomSplitSkill", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def CustomSplitSkill(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid input", status_code=400)

    try:
        # 'values' expected top-level key in the request body
        response_body = {"values": []}
        for value in req_body.get('values', []):
            recordId = value.get('recordId')
            text = value.get('data', {}).get('text', '')

            # Remove sequences of dots, numbers following them, and
            # any additional punctuation or newline characters, replacing them with a single space
            cleaned_text = re.sub(r"[',.\n]+|\d+", ' ', text)

            # Replace multiple spaces with a single space and trim leading/trailing spaces
            cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', cleaned_text).strip()

            # Pattern to match sequences of ". " occurring more than twice
            cleaned_text = re.sub(r"(\. ){3,}", "", cleaned_text)

            chunks = split_text_into_chunks_with_overlap(cleaned_text, chunk_size=256, overlap_size=20)
            
            # response object for specific pdf
            response_record = {
                "recordId": recordId,
                "data": {
                    "textItems": chunks
                }
            }
            response_body['values'].append(response_record)

        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_body), mimetype="application/json")
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Function app crashed", status_code=400)

The inputs and outputs of this skill in the skillset are defined like this:
inputs=[
    InputFieldMappingEntry(name="text", source="/document/content")
],
outputs=[
    OutputFieldMappingEntry(name="textItems", target_name="pages")        
],

How should I extract page information for each chunk?

Can you share the error message which you are getting while executing this code

I get no error. But I can just extract chunks. The data reaching the custom SplitSkill in the request is only text. So I just don't see how this is achievable from my current code status. If at all.

is there a content like Page 1, Page 2.... in your pdf or simple text only?

also, any restrictions to alter your function app?

No restrictions at all in function app modifications. Each page contain a number in the bottom right. But the page contains many other numbers as well. Is you suggestion to try to build a regex expression to catch the page number?

Yeah. because only the content you are passing to function so from content itself you need get information.

I see... Maybe there are enough spaces before the page number to catch it with a specific regex expression. Will try it out.

ok will update if any other approach is there.

You can use generateNormalizedImagePerPage option which applies to pdf only.
Above option will generate data for each page and provides below details.
[
  {
    "data": "BASE64 ENCODED STRING OF A JPEG IMAGE",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 300,
    "originalWidth": 5000,  
    "originalHeight": 3000,
    "rotationFromOriginal": 90,
    "contentOffset": 500,
    "pageNumber": 2
  }
]

Using above details you generate text using Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill and link pageNumber.
All you have to do is.
First, set  Image Action to generateNormalizedImagePerPage in your indexer.

Next, create new fields like pageText  and pageNumber in index.
Then add ocrskillset and link with index, later you do mappings in index projections.
Refer the first solution of this stack question.
This applies if you are using pdf else as i said need extract from content itself.

There must be a better way to add page information than interpret each page in the PDF as an image... What about document intelligence?

As of know in ai search this the way. As image you send it to ocr skill to get text output. Which further you can send it to custom web api. But I would recommend not to use custom web api to chunking since it is already done splitting per page.

I will check with doc intelligence for possible ways

@Mike B Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?

This is a follow up question. I guess non of the options are optimal atm... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78602675/error-when-storing-document-page-in-azure-cognitive-search-service-associated

I guess you haven't checked my solution properly. You no need to interpret the image. Use skillset to get page number

I will check your question.

I have no way of assigning the right pages to each of my chunks by this method. My chunks are not equally long as my pages

In this method, you will get the same page numbers for different chunks. after getting pageText and pagenumber, do text splitting on pageText and pass the results chunks and pageNumber in index projections.
