Error in Azure Cognitive Search Service when storing document page associated to each chunk extracted from PDF in a custom WebApiSkill
I have the following custom WebApiSkill:
@app.route(route="CustomSplitSkill", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def CustomSplit&PageSkill(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid input", status_code=400)

    try:
        # 'values' expected top-level key in the request body
        response_body = {"values": []}
        for value in req_body.get('values', []):
            recordId = value.get('recordId')
            text = value.get('data', {}).get('text', '')

            # Remove sequences of dots, numbers following them, and
            # any additional punctuation or newline characters, replacing them with a single space
            cleaned_text = re.sub(r"[',.\n]+|\d+", ' ', text)

            # Replace multiple spaces with a single space and trim leading/trailing spaces
            cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', cleaned_text).strip()

            # Pattern to match sequences of ". " occurring more than twice
            cleaned_text = re.sub(r"(\. ){3,}", "", cleaned_text)

            chunks, page_numbers = split_text_into_chunks_with_overlap(cleaned_text, chunk_size=256, overlap_size=20)
            
            # response object for specific pdf
            response_record = {
                "recordId": recordId,
                "data": {
                    "textItems": chunks,  # chunks is a str list
                    "numberItems": page_numbers # page_numbers is an int list
                }
            }
            response_body['values'].append(response_record)

        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_body), mimetype="application/json")
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Function app crashed", status_code=400)

The inputs and outputs of this skill in the skillset are defined like this:
inputs=[
    InputFieldMappingEntry(name="text", source="/document/content")
],
outputs=[
    OutputFieldMappingEntry(name="textItems", target_name="pages"),
    OutputFieldMappingEntry(name="numberItems", target_name="numbers")
],

And the SearchIndexerIndexProjectionSelector is configured in the following way:
index_projections = SearchIndexerIndexProjections(  
        selectors=[  
            SearchIndexerIndexProjectionSelector(  
                target_index_name=index_name,  
                parent_key_field_name="parent_id",  
                source_context="/document/pages/*",  
                mappings=[  
                    InputFieldMappingEntry(name="chunk", source="/document/pages/*"),  
                    InputFieldMappingEntry(name="vector", source="/document/pages/*/vector"),  
                    InputFieldMappingEntry(name="title", source="/document/metadata_storage_name"),
                    InputFieldMappingEntry(name="page_number", source="/document/numbers/*"), 
                ],  
            ),  
        ],  
        parameters=SearchIndexerIndexProjectionsParameters(  
            projection_mode=IndexProjectionMode.SKIP_INDEXING_PARENT_DOCUMENTS  
        ),  
    )

My search fields look like this:
fields = [  
        SearchField(
            name="parent_id",
            type=SearchFieldDataType.String,
            sortable=True,
            filterable=True,
            facetable=True
        ),  
        SearchField(
            name="title",
            type=SearchFieldDataType.String
        ),  
        SearchField(
            name="chunk_id",
            type=SearchFieldDataType.String,
            key=True,
            sortable=True,
            filterable=True,
            facetable=True,
            analyzer_name="keyword"
        ),  
        SearchField(
            name="chunk",
            type=SearchFieldDataType.String,
            sortable=False,
            filterable=False,
            facetable=False
        ),  
        SearchField(
            name="vector",
            type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single),
            vector_search_dimensions=1536,
            vector_search_profile_name="myHnswProfile"
        ),
        SearchField(
            name="page_number",
            type=SearchFieldDataType.Int32,
            sortable=True,
            filterable=True,
            facetable=True
        ), 
    ] 

I get the following error:
The data field 'page_number' in the document with key 'xyz' has an invalid value of type 'Edm.String' ('String maps to Edm.String'). The expected type was 'Edm.Int32'.

When changing the value to String the index creation passes, with the following result under page_numbers:
"page_number": "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...]"

But I want to get a single value under each chunk

I already tried to set the searchfield data type to string, as explained under my question. But the whole list is assigned to each chunk.

The list is an int list as I append numerical values to it. So it makes very little sense that it is read as a string list. I am clearly missing something...

Instead of returning a list of page numbers as a single string, return each page number as an individual integer entry in the list.

Convert page_numbers to a list of integers before adding it to the response - page_numbers = list(map(int, page_numbers)) 
This is the sample input I have taken for testing this will be the expected output.

This page_numbers = list(map(int, page_numbers)) did not solve my issue. The error is still the same

The reason you are getting this error because of the source_context in index projection.
The context /document/pages/* is works for chunk because it is present around this context but numbers is present in the /document/numbers/* context, so it is not projecting to target index instead taking literal value.
To make this correct you need to return the list of dictionaries contains chunk and numbers from custom web Api skillset.
Below is the example.
response_record = {
                "recordId": recordId,
                "data": {
                    "subdata": [
                    {'textItems': 'This is string 1.', 'numberItems': 1},
                    {'textItems': 'This is string 2.', 'numberItems': 2},
                    {'textItems': 'This is string 3.', 'numberItems': 3},
                    {'textItems': 'This is string 4.', 'numberItems': 4},
                    {'textItems': 'This is string 5.', 'numberItems': 5},
                    {'textItems': 'This is string 6.', 'numberItems': 6}]
                    
                }
            }

Here, i am returning the field subdata having list dictionary with fields textItems and numberItems.
You can use below code to convert like above.
combined_list = [{'textItems': text, 'numberItems': number} for text, number in zip(chunks, page_numbers)]

Next, you can directly reference this in index projection no need to do output field mappings.
Skillset defination.
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "targetindex",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/subdata/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "chunk",
            "source": "/document/subdata/*/textItems"
          },
          {
            "name": "page_number",
            "source": "/document/subdata/*/numberItems"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {}
  },

Here, i given sourceContext as /document/subdata/* in that i am getting
/document/subdata/*/textItems for chunk and /document/subdata/*/numberItems for page_number.
Output:

Note: Use metadata_storage_path or metadata_filename to differentiate the chunks between each document.
UPDATE
Skillset
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsaisearch.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC8B62DB084EBF\"",
  "name": "skillset1718252807308",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "name": "jgs_func",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document",
      "uri": "https://jgsfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger1?code=TITuBRAeLG0EfpzrhmylNpvEJRITVUUmtb1JKi1MNYXuAzFuLFTeUg==",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "timeout": "PT30S",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "degreeOfParallelism": 1,
      "authResourceId": "",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "content",
          "source": "/document/content"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "subdata",
          "targetName": "subdata"
        }
      ],
      "httpHeaders": {},
      "authIdentity": null
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices",
    "description": null
  },
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "targetindex",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/subdata/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "chunk",
            "source": "/document/subdata/*/textItems",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "page_number",
            "source": "/document/subdata/*/numberItems",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {}
  },
  "encryptionKey": null
}


This looks promising! Trying this out right away

Output field mapping is required by the WebApiSkillset. Right now I am getting: Could not generate projection from input '/document/subdata/*'. Check the 'source' or 'sourceContext' property of your projection in your skillset. =$(/document/subdata/*) ?map { "chunk": $(/document/subdata/*/textItems), "page_number": $(/document/subdata/*/numberItems), "title": $(/document/metadata_storage_name) }

sorry. I'm trying to say you no need of mapping in indexer  but need to give in skillset. I have added skill set definition kindly check it.

Thank you so much for your answer! Based on what you have provided, which now works for chunks and page_numbers. How should the context and input source be set for my AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill?

For you embedding skill context will be /document/subdata/* and input will be
/document/subdata/*/textItems.

I just tried this, I get this error in the AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill: Web Api response status: 'Unauthorized', Web Api response details: '{"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}}'

You azure open ai configuration is wrong. please raise new thread giving proper details with screenhot.
